# Set "scaling" factor with awesome window manager

Tags: font-size, scaling, ubuntu-16.04, awesome-wm

How can one set the scaling factor in awesome window manager of "clients" (= window)?

`xrandr` shows me, that I have a resolution of `2880x1800 59.99*+` But the frames of the browsers and others (e.g. where the titles of the tabs are shown) seem to have font size about 100px. How can I change to a smaller scaling?

Comment: So...  I feel like I don't understand your question correctly, but just reduce the font size in your theme? When you end up with letters 100px in size, then your font size seems to be huge.

Comment: the thing ist, if i change the font size, the top bar (status bar etc...) of awesome will get bigger but not the font size of the client windows...

Comment: Try setting GDK_SCALE=2 in your environment. Is this more like what you want?

Comment: How do I set this? For example Starting firefox with the prefix wont take any effect? (using the command in terminal: "GTK_SCALE=4 firefox")

Comment: GDK, not GTK (and I don't know if GTK2 supports this, not if Firefox does)

Comment: Ah okay, one step further: I can make it bigger, but not smaller...